# My loop is not moving on to the next element in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, post

Follow up to my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62182786/dont-process-next-element-in-foreach-loop-till-the-process-for-first-is-over). I am trying to run a recursive function to process one element at a time in an array.  I, it does not go to want it to process the first element and not start working on the next element in the list until the process for the first one is complete?

This is my array: `arr = ['Hermione', 'Ron', 'Harry']`

```
arr.forEach(d=>{
    $('#the_table>tbody').append(` 
                <tr id='tr_${d}'>
                    <td'>${d}</td>
                    <td><i id='change' class='no'></i></td>
                </tr>
            `);
});
```

```
let finished = 1;
for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
   if (finished === 1 && arr.length !== 0) {
       hp_name = arr[i];
       finished = 0;
    }

   if(finished == 0) {
    const myfunc = () => {
     json_object['name'] = hp_name;
     $.post(api, json_object,
        function(data, status) {
           if (data.value === 'started') {
           setTimeout(myfunc, 5000);
        } else {
           finished = 1;
           $('#change').removeClass('no').addClass('yes');
        }
     }, 'json');
   }
   myfunc();
   if (finished === 1) continue;
   }
}
```

This logic above is just working for the first element and then stopping. Why is it not moving on to the next element in the array and processing that?

It is not moving to next element in the array.

Comment: I don't see where the recursion is. Is this code `myfunc`? A recursive function usually needs parameters, so you can change them in the recursive call and get closer to the base case.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, i just added myFunc to the code. Sorry, I am new to recursive. Can you help me with what I have?

Comment: @Barmar, I edited my question as well. How do I get to the next element?

Comment: Why is the loop using `data.length` as the limit instead of `arr.length`? Also, the test should be `<` rather than `<=`.

Comment: `$.post` is asynchronous. All the loop iterations will run before it ever sets `finished = 1`.

Comment: @Barmar, is there anyway for me to go around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `for` loop. Pass the array index as an argument to the function, and increment it when you make the recursive call.

```js
const myfunc = (i) => {
  if (i >= arr.length) {
    return;
  }
  json_object['name'] = arr[i];
  $.post(api, json_object,
    function(data, status) {
      if (data.value === 'started') {
        setTimeout(function() {
          myfunc(i+1);
        }, 5000);
      } else {
        $('#change').removeClass('no').addClass('yes');
      }
    }, 'json');
}
myfunc(0)
```